# Disjunctive normal form to conjunctive and vice-versa

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Is there a way i can go from dnf to cnf quickly? Can I simply negate dnf to get cnf? and get negate cnf to get dnf?

e.g.

$P \to (Q\wedge \neg (P \to R))$

= $\neg P \vee (Q \wedge \neg ( \neg P \vee R))$

= $\neg P \vee (Q \wedge (P \wedge \neg R))$

= $\neg P \vee (Q \wedge P \wedge \neg R)$    --- is this correctly in DNF?

How could I go from CNF from here? I'm slightly stuck.

Comment: Negating (and then using de Morgan) will get you a CNF from a DNF and vice versa, but they will *not* be equivalent. I doubt that this is what you want.

Comment: Yup, you're right, I need them to be equivalent. Would I use distrubtivity laws?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You've got it in DNF. To convert to CNF use the distributive law: $A \vee (B \wedge C) = (A \vee B) \wedge (A \vee C)$

$$\neg P \vee (Q \wedge P \wedge \neg R) \leftrightarrow
  (\neg P \vee Q) \wedge (\neg P \vee (P \wedge \neg R)) \leftrightarrow
  (\neg P \vee Q) \wedge (\neg P \vee P) \wedge (\neg P \wedge \neg R) 
$$

(of course the $\neg P \vee P$ can be canceled).

For more information...

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form

Comment: Much appreciated, thanks everybody. So the trick is to use distrubtivity laws to switch between the two and then apply cancellations. Many thanks.

Comment: Yep! It will cause it to grow in length, but there's nothing inherently tricky about it. :)

Comment: Many thanks, had me very confused at first

Comment: Note if mere equisatisfiability (rather than equivalence) is all you need, you can save yourself an exponential blow-up for DNF->CNF by using the Tseitin transform (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tseitin_transformation).